# Nginx set proxy_set_header if header is present

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using AWS CloudFront to terminate my SSL before hitting my backend, and need to distinguish this traffic from non-CloudFront traffic to set a `proxy_set_header` in Nginx.

I believe the best way to do this would be to check for the `X-Amz-Cf-Id` header ([added by CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior)), and set the `proxy_set_header` when it's present. However, I'm aware it's not possible to set `proxy_set_header` in an Nginx if statement, which leads to my question.

How can I set a `proxy_set_header` value only when that header is present?

Comment: Can't you set that header in the amazon cloud front when it terminates SSL?

Comment: Thanks @seb, I've tried setting custom headers as header name = `proxy_set_header` and value = `X-Forwarded-Proto https` but it's not working as expected.

I need to add this to a specific line of my Nginx configuration so don't think that approach would work. My ultimate goal is to tell my app that CF connections are over HTTPS.

Comment: I don't use cloud front, but a quick search gave me this result: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html So cloud front is able to set headers. If cloud front can set the header, than it would make much more sense to set the header there than in nginx. Or you can search and find this solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/506972/nginx-why-i-cant-put-proxy-set-header-inside-an-if-clause

Comment: Thanks, I had read those pages you linked but haven't been able to figure it out. As mentioned I've set the header in CloudFront. According to [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/808990/proxy-set-header-not-working), the `proxy_set_header` directive sets headers that Nginx sends to the backend, so I believe I still need the directive in Nginx, please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: I checked the request headers coming from CloudFront and they include `CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto: https`, so I'm setting `proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $http_cloudfront_forwarded_proto;` which seems to be doing the job. I guess that variable becomes nil when not available. Will test some more and mark this as the answer if it holds out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general answer is that you can set variables in `if` and then use the variable. Like this:

```
set $variable "";
if ($http_X_Amz_Cf_Id) {
  set $variable "somevalue";
}
proxy_set_header someheader $variable;
```

Comment: Is this not subject to this caveat:
"Nginx's "if" block effectively creates a (nested) location block and once the "if" condition matches, only the content handler of the inner location block (i.e., the "if" block) will be executed."
- http://agentzh.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html ?

Comment: Yes, but the inner location block (the "if") inherits the content handler of the outer block (it itself does not have one). Your link mentions this: "3. The inner block does not has any content handler, ngx_proxy inherits the content handler (that of ngx_proxy) in the outer scope (see src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c:2025)."

Answer (score 15):

`if` statements aren't a good way of setting custom headers because they may [cause statements outside the if block to be ignored](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

You can use a [map directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) instead which is not prone to the same problems.

```
# outside server blocks
map $http_X_Amz_Cf_Id $is_cloudfront {
    default "No";
    ~. "Yes";  # Regular expression to match any value
}
```

Then:

```
# inside location block
proxy_set_header X_Custom_Header $is_cloudfront;
```

Comment: Should be acceptable answer for suggesting map. Haven't tested the ~. "Yes" though.

Comment: But it's prone to the issue that it needs to be oustide of the server block, which in some cases is not an option (eg: plesk)